# Is there a way to better filter through YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, video, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

Is there a way to better filter through YouTube videos? The standard filter is pretty limited.

For example, what if I want to sort by most liked videos, but only see videos with more than 1,000 views? Is there some addon that would allow me to do that pherhaps?

[image]